# Did I select the correct answer for this question about time complexity of an algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

The question is:

[image]

I said that this statement is wrong since there exists no constants *k1* and *k2* such that *k1**n < 2^log(n)+n^3/2/30^30+log(n)^10 < k2*n when *n* gets large enough.

I'm still really having trouble understanding Big O notation, so I am not sure if this is the correct justification.

Comment: n^(3/2) / L = O(n^(3/2)) for any L real value.Without looking to other coefficients I can say your answer is correct, ie the statement is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that `log` stands for `log_10`, the logarithm in base `10`. And let's say `lg` denotes the logarithm in base `2`. Then

```
log n = (lg n)(log 2),
```

which can be verified by taking `log` on both sides of `n = 2^(lg n)`.

From the first equation we deduce that

```
2^(log n) = n^(log 2)
```

thus, the first term is `θ(n^(log 2))`, where `log 2 ≈ 0.301`. The second term is `θ(n^1.5)`. Therefore the sum of the first two terms is `θ(n^1.5)`. And since `n^1.5` also dominates `(log n)^10`, we get that the answer is `θ(n^1.5)`.